# I have passed a certification that I have been told I will do, should I tell my work?

Tags: communication, certification

I will be starting a new job in October. During one of the interviews I had, I asked:

> What sort of training will I get?

The response was that there would be training on the job, as well as the opportunity to pass one or more Microsoft certifications (starting with the [Azure Fundamentals certification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/azure-fundamentals/).) Each certification can be done as an individual, not as part of a corporate body. I have already passed the initial exam (Azure Fundamentals).

I hesitate as I am not the only person starting (there are around ~5 other people starting along with me in the same/similar role) and I don't want to appear as arrogant by answering questions, if there is company-organised training with my colleagues, as I assume there would be.

When would be a good time, if any to make the company aware of this?

Comment: Had you already passed the exam when you did the interview, or was it subsequent to that but before starting the job itself?

Comment: @seventyeightist I completed the exam after the interview

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> When would be a good time, if any to make the company aware of this?

Right away. If you don't want to seem arrogant, just let them know privately by email.

In other words, give them the information now, and let them decide whether you should still train with the others, whether you should try to get the next level in the certificate, or whether you should do some other training, or whether you should start working right away.

Just look at it from this perspective.

Unless you want to retake the same exam again and waste your company money, you will need to tell them at some point. And it's better that you let them know now than later. It will allow them to plan things accordingly.

Comment: It wouldn't only be wasting the company's money - it'd also be wasting OP's time. Who wants to sit through a training course and exam they've already done?

Comment: Who cares less if company money "is wasted" ?  Huh?  COmpanies waste money like niagra waste water, it's a non-issue.  What companies want is simply regularity and systems.

Comment: +1 - and OP has the opportunity here to set themselves apart from the others by having been proactive in already getting ahead with the Azure knowledge they'll (presumably) need on-the-job. OP should absolutely make it known to the manager/company. (How the manager/company handles this with the others is a different and in some ways more difficult question,  since if they are being taken on as a group, the others' expectation will probably be that OP will be on the training with them.)

Comment: @Fattie It could be seen as fraud by Microsoft (as noted by seventyeightist) and I’m no fraudster

Comment: @Boolean , you seem top already "know the answer you're asking for".  If so just send a trivial five word email "I already have certification XYZ".  State the fact and nothing else, it's a trivial issue and nobody will "think one way or another" about it.

Comment: @Fattie If the company wants to waste money, that's a decision for them to make, not the OP to make on their behalf. Not every company is the same.

Comment: the bottom line is, the situation seems to be the OP is "worrying about nothing". OP to send a trivial five word email "I already have certification XYZ". State the fact and nothing else, it's a trivial issue and nobody will "think one way or another" about it.

Answer (score 5):

In case you worry a lot about *"what will people think"*, I just want to add -

1. Please learn to speak up and express yourself without overly worrying about what other people think. You have no idea what someone will think of you because everyone has a different personality and life experience.
2. It's a huge unreasonable burden you take upon yourself when you try to think for someone else first, weighing your words carefully, before you speak.
3. One way to be free of this habit is to understand and accept that adults can express their thoughts honestly. This means that if somebody is happy or annoyed with you, they can convey this to you in a socially appropriate manner.
4. This ofcourse means that as an adult, you too need to learn how to express your thoughts honestly, in a socially appropriate manner. You have no control over anyone's thought process. What you can control is what you think (about yourself, about others or some situation) and how you choose to express it.
5. The main thing to remember is what you say should be "*socially appropriate*". This means being mindful of cultural contexts, relationship level, and etiquette before expressing your thoughts.

(Sometimes people will be jerk. Sometimes people will misunderstand despite your best intentions. And sometimes you will just have to accept people for who they are, even if you don't like them. But if you learn to be honest with yourself and to others, all this won't bother you as much as trying to guess what people think of you.)